# VBA - Create a new worksheet and add a suffix if the worksheet name already exists

Tags: vba, naming, worksheet

I am very new at VBA. I would like to create new worksheet and name it from cell (A1) of the main worksheet. I want to add a suffix "(1)" after the new worksheet name if it is already in use. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: What suffix should be added if `Name(1)` exists?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the below and it seems to do what you're asking for. The suffix increases incrementally depending on how many of a named sheet you have in the workbook. There are probably better ways of doing it though and I'm no real VBA expert.

Credit to another answer here which I adapted for your question: [Excel VBA Trying to create a new worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209989/excel-vba-trying-to-create-a-new-worksheet?rq=1)

```
Sub addWorksheet()
Dim worksheetName As Variant
Dim i As Integer

i = 0

worksheetName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    worksheetExists = (InStr(1, ws.Name, worksheetName, vbTextCompare) = 1)
    
    If worksheetExists Then
        
        i = i + 1
        
    End If
    
Next ws

If i > 0 Then

    worksheetName = worksheetName & "(" & i & ")"
    
End If

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        .Name = worksheetName
End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below covers all possible scenarios of incremental numeric suffix addition, behaving the same way as when you duplicate a sheet:

```
Option Explicit
Dim sheetname As String, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long


Sub New_Sheet_Rename()                            'create a new sheet and rename it
    sheetname = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value                    'or whatever name
    Set NewSheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    NewSheet.Name = sheetname + suffix
End Sub


Function suffix()           'define a numerical suffix if sheet intended name already exists
    suffix = ""                     'no suffix as default
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count                           'check each sheet for intended name
        If Worksheets(i).Name = sheetname Then              'if intended name exists:
            For j = 1 To 100                                    'check each suffix possible number ('100' is arbitrary)
                suffix = "(" & j & ")"                              'define numeric suffix
                For k = 1 To Sheets.Count                               'check each sheet for intended name + suffix
                    If Worksheets(k).Name = sheetname & suffix Then         'if suffix already exists:
                        suffix = "(" & j + 1 & ")"                              'add +1
                        Exit For                                                'don't need to check remaining sheets
                    End If
                Next k
                If suffix = "(" & j & ")" Then Exit For                 'the smaller available suffix number will be used; don't need to check larger numbers
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```